# How to get a variable from JavaScript to ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, cfml

I'm currently working on one issue and I need some help. I'm working on HTML code that fills in special machine labels. It is a kind of web page on where people fill in the number of lines and text size, then enter the text of the lines they want the resulting table to contain in each line.

**I need advice on how to save JavaScript variable to cf variable.** We use ColdFusion to link the code to DB.

Here is a small sample of the problem.

```
for(let a = 1; a <= g_rowCounter; a++){
    text = getVal('i_row-input_' + a);
    g_texts.push(text);
}
```

Is there anyone who would encounter a similar problem or know how to solve it?

**Thank you for all the answers.**

Here is for reference whole code to lock at the problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Stitek</title>
        
        <script>
            var g_rowCounter = 0;
            var g_texts = [];
            
            function vygenerujInputy(){
                var rowCount = parseInt(getVal('i_row-count'));
                var inputWrp = byId('i_row-inputs_wrp');
                var oneInput = null;
                
                inputWrp.innerHTML = '';
                
                for(let a = 1; a <= rowCount; a++){
                    var defText = '';
                    if(g_texts[a - 1]){
                        defText = g_texts[a - 1];
                    }
                    
                    oneInput = createRowInput(a, defText);

                    inputWrp.appendChild(oneInput);
                }
                
                g_rowCounter = rowCount;
            }

            function createRowInput(number, defText){
                var r = document.createElement('div');
                
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.setAttribute('id', 'i_row-input_' + number);
                input.setAttribute('class', 'c_row-input');
                input.value = defText;
                
                var numberSpan = document.createElement('span');
                numberSpan.innerHTML = number + ')&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                
                r.appendChild(numberSpan);
                r.appendChild(input);
                
                return r;
            }
            
            function getVal(htmlId){
                var r = byId(htmlId).value;
                return r;
            }

            function byId(htmlId){
                var r = document.getElementById(htmlId);
                return r;
            }
            
            function VygenerujVystup(){
                
            }

            function vygenerujTabulku(){
                var outputWrp = byId('i_vystupni-div');
                outputWrp.innerHTML = '';

                if(g_rowCounter < 1){
                    window.alert('nejprve zvol počet řádků');
                } else {
                    var textSize = parseInt(getVal('i_velikost-textu'));
                    
                    if(textSize < 6 || textSize > 75){
                        window.alert('velikost textu musi byt v intervalu od 6 do 75 mm');
                    } else {
                        var frameSize = parseInt(getVal('i_sirka-ramecku'));
                        
                        /*
                        if(frameSize < 1){
                            window.alert('sirka ramecku musi byt vetsi nez 0');
                        } else {
                            outputWrp.style.width = frameSize + 'px';
                        */   
                            g_texts = [];

                            var text = '';
                            var oneRowDom = null;

                            for(let a = 1; a <= g_rowCounter; a++){
                                text = getVal('i_row-input_' + a);
                                g_texts.push(text);
                            }

                            

                            for(let a = 0; a < g_texts.length; a++){
                                oneRowDom = createWrappedSpan('jeden-radek', g_texts[a], textSize);
                                outputWrp.appendChild(oneRowDom);
                            }    
                       // }  
                    }
                }
            }

            //kdyz textSize je vetsi nez 0, nastavi se velikost textu podle tohoto cisla. jinak se necha vychozi velikost
            function createWrappedSpan(rawClassName, text, textSize){
                var r = document.createElement('div');
                r.setAttribute('class', 'c_' + rawClassName + '_wrp');

                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.setAttribute('class', 'c_' + rawClassName + '_text');
                span.innerHTML = text;

                if(textSize > 0){
                    span.style.fontSize = textSize + 'px';
                }
                
                r.appendChild(span);

                return r;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>

      <cfform>
        <b>Zvol počet řádků štítku &nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
    
        <cfselect name="srows" id="i_row-count" onchange="vygenerujInputy()">
            <option value="0" name="m00" size="50" maxlength="30" type="text">0    
            <option value="1" name="m01" size="50" maxlength="30" type="text">1
            <option value="2" name="m02" size="50" maxlength="30" type="text">2
            <option value="3" name="m03" size="50" maxlength="30" type="text">3
            <option value="4" name="m04" size="50" maxlength="30" type="text">4
            <option value="5" name="m05" size="50" maxlength="30" type="text">5
        </cfselect>
      
        <!--
            Výběr hodnot - počtu řádků - 1 - 5.
        -->
        <br><br>
        <div id="i_row-inputs_wrp" class="c_row-inputs_wrp"></div>
        <br>
        <span>velikost textu (milimetry)&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><cfinput type="number" name="quantity" id="i_velikost-textu" min="6" max="75" range = "6,75" validate = "integer">
        <br>
        <!--
            Velikost textu je omezena od 6ti do 75ti.
        -->
        
      </cfform>
        
        <br>
        <button onclick="vygenerujTabulku()" class="c_form-button">Náhled štítku</button>
        <br>

        <div class="c_vystup_wrp" id="i_vystupni-div">
        
        </div>
        
      <cfform>
      
        <cfset pr1 = "input1">
        <cfset pr2 = "input2">
        <cfset pr3 = "input3">
        <cfset pr4 = "input4">
        <cfset pr5 = "input5">
      <cfset pr6 = "vyska">
      <cfset pr7 = "sirka">
      
      <cfoutput>#pr1#<br>#pr2#<br>#pr3#<br>#pr4#<br>#pr5#<br>#pr6#<br>#pr7#<br></cfoutput>
        
        <cfselect name="swidth" id="i_sirka-ramecku" onchange="vygenerujTabulku()">    
        </cfselect>
      </cfform>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basically, all you need to do is to grab all the javascript data,  bundle it into a container and send it per ajax request (e.g. as a form post) to a .cfm template or a cfc component file. Then the data will be available as a form variable, which you can save or use how ever you need.

Comment: And avoid `<cfform>`

Comment: You're building a form. The standard way to get the form data to the server is to post the form. Make an `<input type="submit">` and send the form to the server. Use `<cfdump var="#FORM#">` in the receiving the CFML to see what you've got. Make sure that all your `<input>` fields have a `name`. The ID is only for the JavaScript, the *name* and *value* is what is sent to the server.

Comment: `Make sure that all your <input> fields have a name`  ... otherwise, the fields won't be submitted to the server, and you'll be scratching your head wondering why they don't appear in the `form` scope when the form is submitted.

Comment: @AndreasRu could you send an example of how the ajax request would look? I'm not sure how to send a javascript array (or whatever you had in mind) in an ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, in order to use the values in CF, the form data must be submitted to the CF server via an http request (ajax, basic form submit, etc..).
For example, perform a simple form post:

- Add `method="POST"` and a submit button to the form
- Assign a `name` to the label fields. Otherwise, their values won't be sent to the server.

  ```
   // Dynamically assign the names "label_1", "label_2", etc.. 
   function createRowInput(number, defText){
       // ...
       input.setAttribute('name', 'label_' + number);
       // ... 
   }


   <!--- CFForm doesn't provide much benefit, so use a plain html `<form>` --->
   <form method="post" action="TheReceivingPageHere.cfm">
       <b>Zvol počet řádků štítku &nbsp;&nbsp;</b>  

       ... more code ....

       <input type="submit" value="Odeslat hodnoty">
   </form>
  ```

Dump the `form` scope on the receiving page, and you'll see something like this when the form is submitted:

[image: Dump of Form scope]

Use the number of fields, i.e. `form.srows`, to extract the label values dynamically

```
<cfparam name="form.sRows" default="0">

<cfloop from="1" to="#form.srows#" index="r">
    <!--- extract value of "label_1", "label_2", ... --->
    <cfset variables.labelValue = form["label_"& r]>

    ... do something with values...
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot.